# How can I get the first line of a csv file in JavaScript (node) synchronously and without using promises?

Tags: javascript, node.js, file

I need to get the first line of a csv file in Node. The problem that I am facing is that I can't get the columns name before processing the rows of the csv. The extension of the file is not important actually, I just want to find a way to get the first line of a file in a synchronous way.

```
const filename = 'test.csv'


const get_firstline = () => {
    //return filename.firstline
}

const process_firstline = (firstline) => {
    console.log(firstline)
}

process_firstline(get_firstline())
```

I need an implementation for the get_firstline function. I am a noob in in Node (JavaScript in general actually).

Comment: I/O (reading/writing from files) is inherently asynchronous. I don't think it's possible to do it without at least a callback function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the below code snippet :

```
const fs = require('fs');

try {
  var file = fs.readFileSync('PASS YOUR CSV PATH HERE', 'utf-8');
  const lines = file.split('\n');
  const headers = lines[0];
  console.log(headers);
} catch (error) {
  console.error(error);
}
```